# Foldmethod=marker, how to customize?

Tags: vim

With `foldmethod=marker` folded portions appear like this:

```
+--27 lines: First section
+--16 lines: Second section
etc ...
```

How can I get rid of the `+--XX` lines: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the text displayed for a fold by defining a custom function that generates the text you want displayed and changing the `foldtext` option to call your function.

Take a look at [jpython_fold.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2527) for an example of this.

Also see `:help 'foldtext'`.